# How to have a row number like in Excel in the left in DT?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I want to have a row number in the left that always shows `1, 2, 3, ...` (just like excel row number) such that user have a reference row number to see the interested row's rank after clicked on column to change the order of table.

EDIT:

```r
library(DT)
n <- 20
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(customer_id = sample(10),
           amount_2016 = round(runif(n) * 16),
           amount_2017 = round(runif(n) * 17),
           amount_2018 = round(runif(n) * 18),
           amount_2019 = round(runif(n) * 19))

datatable(df)
```

[image: The default]

After click on `amount_2016`, it shows

[image: order by amount_2016]

It shows `17, 14, 1, 2, 15, ...` and I want it keeps to be `1, 2, 3, ...` just like in Excel

Comment: can you please print your expected output

Comment: I don't think this is possible, the row names (what you are calling row rank) are matched with the rest of the data in that row, so must also be moved based on the sort.

Comment: Maybe whis will help: https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html.

Comment: @PawełChabros Yes. That's what I need. I don't know that much about javascript. Can you provide an example using `DT`?

Comment: @H.Yong Unfortunetly I can't because I don't know how to implement it :D But I'am trying to figure it out... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to define a `callback` `JS()` function that implements the [`table.on` behaviour](https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html) of a dynamic row number counter.

Here is a minimal reproducible RMarkdown example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(DT)
datatable(
    iris,
    callback = JS("
    table.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
        table.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( 
            function (cell, i) {
                cell.innerHTML = i+1;
            } );
    } )"))
```
````

producing

[image]

No matter how you order the columns, the row number will always stay the same as 1, 2, 3, ...

Comment: Too late for me, I was going to post the same... I've found this way here: https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html

Comment: No worries @StéphaneLaurent;-) from what I found over the years, most DataTables methods can be implemented in one way or the other in `DT::datatable`. By the way, the link you give is the same as the one that I refer to in my post, and that PawełChabros mentioned in his comment above.

Comment: Ah indeed, I didn't see. Sorry for the useless comment ^^